# Hololens camera animation pathing issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

When using the unity editor all animations tied to the camera work, but when build and deployed onto the hololens the animation wont process(being overridden by real life coordinates), the way to get around this is by attaching it to a random gameObject. My issue is giving the user the ability to roam around space whilst tying animations and force movements to the cameras parent(empty gameObject). 
I have tried making the gameobject stay where the camera is but obviously this just makes for constant motion.

Is there any way to keep the cameras parent exactly where the camera is in order to stop the animations going glitchy?

Comment: I think you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. The camera object for hololens compilation is more of an initial reference point. Some of the properties and methods you can do to it work, to a degree, but a *lot* don't. E.g. you can't add a second camera to get an overlay render.  So I suspect you're trying to do something that would be more appropriate to do another way, rather than shoving the camera around.

Comment: I don't want to add a second camera. I've kind of fixed this by destroying the parent object that the animation patching works on and assigning the camera to be a child of a new gameobject that I create at he same space of the camera.

Comment: I wasn't telling you to add a second camera, I was *using the idea as an example* of something that doesn't work on the HoloLens.